# Arguments of Hecke-eigenvalues

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $p$ be a prime and $\chi$ a primitive character mod $p$. Consider the orthonormal basis $B_k(q,\chi)$ of $S_k(q,\chi)$, the space of all weight $k$, level $p$ holomorphic forms with character $p$. Since $\chi$ is primitive, $B_k(q,\chi)$ consists of new forms, and the Hecke-eigenvalue $\lambda_f(p)$ makes sense. It is known that $|\lambda_f(p)|=p^{(k-1)/2}$. I would like to know how the "argument" of $\lambda_f(p)$ depends on $\chi$: can it be expressed in terms of some other quantities, like Gauss sums?

Thanks.

Comment: The argument $\lambda_{f}(p)$ doesn't "depend" on $\chi$ in the sense that it's not the same for all new forms in $B_{k}(q,\chi)$. It can be expressed in terms of the sign of the functional equation for $L(f,s)$. I suspect this doesn't answer your question, though.